# NextGen Gallery template cache

Tags: templates, cache, plugin-nextgen-gallery

I've implemented a custom Isotope template for the NextGen Gallery plugin, and I've made changes and bug fixes to the template, but when I refresh the page the template changes have not taken effect.

I tested the cache of my browser by making changes to other theme template files, such as *header.php*, etc. The browser recognizes these changes immediately, but the NextGen Gallery template is still on an old version.

Any idea of how to flush this cache and reload this template file with each new change?

Answer (score 6):

NextGEN Gallery 2.0 caches galleries and albums in transients (plus their own custom transient expiration time record). You can clear the cache by deleting all transients.

Easiest way is to install a plugin like [Delete Expired Transients](http://wordpress.org/plugins/delete-expired-transients/) and delete all transients from the Tools menu -- that plugin has an option for deleting either expired transients or all transients, and will delete NextGEN Gallery's custom expiration record too.

Or you can just run this in MySQL:

```
delete from wp_options
where option_name like '\_transient\_%'
or option_name like '\_site\_transient\_%'
or option_name like 'displayed\_galleries\_%'
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a bit late, but I just overcame this issue myself.

If you go to 'Gallery > Other Options > Miscellaneous' you will see a "Clear image cache" button. That should solve the problem.

I haven't found a way to permanently adjust caching, but this works.

Hope this helps someone.